# Is List<MyCustomObj> less or more performant than maintaining x List of what MyCustomObj contains in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In a project that I am in there is a section of the code that must be very performant. Preferably less memory footprint and faster code.

I have been told that if I have the following obj

```
MyCustomObj
    MyProperty_id: String
    MyProperty1: Long
    MyProperty2: Boolean
```

It is more performant to store 3 list

```
List<String>
List<Long>
List<Boolean>
```

than having `List<MyCustomObj>` .

I cannot find any documentation on this, is this true?

Comment: It's pre-optimization. Do what best fits your requirements, and don't worry about performance gains like this unless you need them (determined via profiling).

Comment: Its already decided, I am just wondering where is the saving coming from for my own educational purpose, since I couldn't get a satisfactory explanation

Comment: How is the data used? Iterating through three lists is slower than iterating through one `List<MyCustomObj>`.

Comment: Only 1 list is iterated, the list containing the id, all other list is access through index, same index correspond to same data

Comment: But you still have to build three lists. And which `List` implementations are you using?

Comment: There is no clear difference between both solutions. A few bytes of memory difference. I would usually not use #2 because it looks like terrible code. And unless you can prove with proper profiling that it performs better and that the performance gain is relevant I'd not allow bad code.

Comment: #2 would force boxing for everything, which probably outweighs the savings from avoiding the MyCustomObj object headers.

Comment: This seems to be a distorted version of the idea that in case of *primitive values*, it can be more efficient to have distinct *arrays*, e.g. `long[] prop1; boolean[] prop2;` instead of an array of objects each have a `long` and a `boolean` property. Talking about high performance and using boxed `Long` and `Boolean` at the same time doesn’t look like they know what they are talking about. But generally, if anyone says “x is better than y”, they should be able to explain *why*, otherwise it’s just hot air.